# Login issue with subdomain installs

Tags: wp-admin, users, login, cookies, session

I have two Wordpress instances, both of them have [multi-site](https://wordpress.org/support/article/glossary/#multisite) setups.

The issue is: the two instances do not seem to work together in terms of login. I sometimes can't login to the second instance when I have an existing session on the first. As much as possible, I want them to be completely separate from each other because they have separate admin user databases.

Here's the setup. I've changed the hostnames, but hopefully they should be clear.

**Instance 1**

The first instance serves the following admin urls.

```
photo.example.com/wp-admin/
video.example.com/wp-admin/
album.example.com/wp-admin/
```

wp-config.php does not contain anything specific to cookies.

**Instance 2**

The second instance serves only:
unique.example.com/wp-admin/

wp-config.php contains the following:

```
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'unique.example.com' );
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.example.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by separate admin user databases? I'm unsure what you mean in your question but I suspect you mean you have 2 multisite installs that are subdomain installs, and they both live on the same TLD, sharing subdomains. As a result, they both have share the same cookie domain. This is going to be very problematic. The best practice answer would be not to be in this situation or to change the cookie domain so they differ. Otherwise you might need to accept that login will be on a per subdomain basis, not an multisite-wide bases, and every subdomain will require you to login

Comment: I mean they are separate Wordpress installs, so they have different databases. Yes, that's my situation. Thinking of the setup, it seems like a common use case. How to I change the cookie domain? I simply changed the second instance to have .unique.example.com, but that didn't work..

Comment: that would only work if that install had all its subdomains as *.unique.example.com too, cookie domains have to match the domains/URLs being used. Note that cookie domains aren't a WP thing, they're a HTTP/HTML/browser thing. Your situation is very unusual, normally if people have more than 1 multisite install on a subdomain, they have multisite1.example.com and multisite2.example.com, then use URLs such as site1.multisite1.example.com or tomsite.multisite2.example.com, so that Nginx/Apache configs are easier, and cookie domains work out of the box

Comment: sorry, the two installs do not share the same subdomains. The first install contains a few subdomains (not including .unique.example.com) and the second install contains only .unique.example.com. Do I need to specify cookie domain on wp-config.php in this case?

Comment: So I've re-read your original question several times, and I believe I've figured out what you mean by overlapping multisites. You have 2 multisites sitting at the same address. 1 multisite serves `multisite.example.com`. The other multisite servers `site1.multisite.example.com` `site2.multisite.example.com` etc. This is extremely unusual, and ill advised. In this situation, what is the address of the root site of the second multisite? And if the first multisite has more than 1 site, what kind of addresses do they have?

Comment: My understanding of this setup is that you have 2 WP installs installed to the same address, and you're controlling which one gets served based on server configuration or a reverse proxy. I would **strongly** advise against this, and it does not surprise me that you have ran into problems, this is not normal and highly unusual/exotic